Why sentences are either true or false in first-order logic?
In propositional logic a proposition is either true or false, from what I understand, because of the law of excluded middle (LEM) -- propositional variables can only be true or false. The fact that every valid formula built from propositional variables is true or false follows easily from induction.
In first-order language a sentence is either true or false in a given interpretation $I$. This seems to rely on the following definition:
Extend $\phi$ to formulas: Given an assignment $\phi$ in $L$, we further extend $\phi$ so that it assigns a truth value $T$ or $F$ to each formula $A$ of the language $L$; in other words, $\phi:FOR\rightarrow\{T,F\}$.
So the fact that sentences are either true or false in FOL seem to be due to this definition which simply enforces LEM. Is this correct?

Being true or false is a property of the interpretation of a sentence, so of course it has to do with how the interpretation is defined, but that's a bit of a strange conclusion. Indeed LEM forces models of classical logic to have a more "binary" flavour than models of intuitionistic logic.

@MauroALLEGRANZA slightly off topic, but is this the reason the "I am false" sentence can't be defined in PA? The boolean interpretation of sentences in PA does not allow defining a sentence that would be both true and false?

In propositional logic an interpretation is an assignment of truth values to atoms.
The semantics for Classic logic forces us to bivalence and LEM. This approach is naturally extended to interpretations for predicate logic, with the additional definitions needed to manage quantifiers and free variables.
Bivalence means only two values allowed and LEM means that every sentence must have exactly one of them.
Liar-like sentences are problematic because standard predicate logic have troubles with a true( ) predicate.

I'm not sure about that "true( ) predicate" part. A predicate asserting $P$ is true is $P$. (Very different from saying $P$ is provable, as in Gödel's theorems.) I'd say it's because there's no way to represent "this predicate" within this predicate.
